# tornado authentication

Tags: tornado

I am using Tornado to authenticate with 3rd party like twitter.

My login handler looks like this

```
class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.TwitterMixin, tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument('oauth_token', None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
            return
        self.authorize_redirect("/auth/login")
        return

    def _on_auth(self, user):
        if not user:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Twitter auth failed")
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
        return
```

My question is, do I need a redirect statement in _on_auth after setting the secure cookie? Doesn't return take you back to the calling function. This auth handler is being called by the login decorater. Also what is the significane of next in /auth/login?next= in most of the examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to redirect yourself. `_on_auth` is called asynchronously, so `return` does not take you to the calling function: that's done and gone, already!

Regarding `/auth/login?next=xxx`, the next parameter is set to be the originating page from where the request was first redirected to the login page. It is used once `_on_auth` succeeds to redirect to it.

At the end of `_on_auth`, redirect with:

```
self.redirect(self.get_argument('next', '/'))
```

Comment: What happens if `?next=http://target.com/annoythem` ? Wouldn't this be a slight issue of security? Perhaps `next` should be checked to be relative?